# Apache load balancing not working properly | mod_jk

Tags: apache, apache2, load-balancing

I have two jboss application server (on different machines and ip address) and I have setup apache as web server for this application server using mod_jk configuration. Apache web server is also setup to load balance between these two application servers.

Following is the content of my workers.properties file:

```
worker.list=portalworker1,portalworker2,portalbalancer

worker.portalbalancer.type=lb
worker.portalbalancer.balance_workers=portalworker1,portalworker2

worker.portalbalancer.sticky_session=True

# Application server 1 Portal application
worker.portalworker1.type=ajp13
worker.portalworker1.host=10.178.197.91
worker.portalworker1.port=8009
worker.portalworker1.lbfactor=1

# Application server 2 Portal application
worker.portalworker2.type=ajp13
worker.portalworker2.host=10.178.197.90
worker.portalworker2.port=8009
worker.portalworker2.lbfactor=1
```

The problem is that currently request is being sent to any of the application server (for eg. one request at application server 1 and the second request to application server 2) which will obv. won't work.

I have also checked mod_jk log in debug mode:

For 1st request

```
[Tue Dec 13 16:46:12.222 2011] [16097:47166030803776] [debug] get_most_suitable_worker::jk_lb_worker.c (946): searching worker for partial sessionid UH76jWj-q2yX39prlS-nBA**
[Tue Dec 13 16:46:12.222 2011] [16097:47166030803776] [debug] get_most_suitable_worker::jk_lb_worker.c (1001): found best worker portalworker2 (portalworker2) using method 'Request'
```

For 2nd request:

```
[Tue Dec 13 16:46:12.434 2011] [16100:47166030803776] [debug] get_most_suitable_worker::jk_lb_worker.c (946): searching worker for partial sessionid UH76jWj-q2yX39prlS-nBA**
[Tue Dec 13 16:46:12.434 2011] [16100:47166030803776] [debug] get_most_suitable_worker::jk_lb_worker.c (1001): found best worker portalworker1 (portalworker1) using method 'Request'
```

This also ensures that the sessionid's for 2 requset are same, still different workers are found.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had not added jvmRoute in my server.xml for my different application server to differentiate these servers, and also useJK was not set to true in jboss-service.xml file.